Issues with FindTransferAnchors in Seurat v5 with BPCells
I am using a BPCells with my Seurat v5 object. I am trying to run FindTransferAnchors but am having issues with my two datasets. The query Seurat objects counts layers is a dgCMatrix and the reference Seurat Object's counts layer is an IterableMatrix. Does the counts layer in my reference Seurat object need to be converted from a IterableMatrix to a dgCMatrix? How do I convert it to a dgCMatrix?
When I try to perform findtransferanchors on the reference object with the Iterable Matrix and the query object with the dgCMatrix I receive the following error: Error in rowMeans2(x = reference.data): Argument 'x' must be of type logical, integer or numeric, not 'list'.
